# Ant compiling but not running or creating jar

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

The Ant build below compiles successfully.

Unfortunately, it doesn't execute the run step despite the `depends` attribute specifying execute the run target after compile step completed successfully.

It also doesn't create a jar file in the specified classpath.

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project default="run" name="My Project">
<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="com.company.program.project">
        <classpath path="staging\" location="C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\"/>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="compile">
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="staging">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins">
            <!-- <include name="**/*.jar" /> -->
            <include name="org.eclipse.swt.*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</javac>
</target>

<jar destfile="./build/jars/swtgui.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
     <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.swtgui.MainGui" />
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
    </manifest>

    <fileset dir="./bin/com/company/program/project" includes="**/*.class" />
    <fileset dir="C:\my_work\Eclipse\3.6-64\plugins\" includes="org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.6.0.v3650b.jar" />

</jar>

<record name="./project.log" loglevel="verbose" action="start"/>
```

EDIT: Got it to run.  Did not edit the build.xml, but went to `Project Explorer -> build.xml -> External Tool Configurations -> Build -> Targets` and for some reason the run target was unchecked.

I checked it and now the `run` target runs, but produces the error log below.

```
run:
 [java] running com.company.project.program with default permissions     (exit forbidden)
     [java] Running in same VM Executing 'com.company.project.program'
The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
     [java] Could not find com.company.project.program. Make sure you have it in your classpath
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:140)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:834)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:228)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:137)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:110)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at         org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at     org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:142)
         [java] Java Result: -1
    run:  duration 0 seconds
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Do I need to do anymore editing to the xml file to get this to run and create a jar?

Comment: Do not use ant. Use maven or gradle

Comment: I'm forced to use ant. :(

Comment: Try running `ant -verbose -debug` and check/post the output.
Absolute Windows paths are a pretty bad sign, but I'm not sure this is the problem. Generally your build file does not look good.

Comment: I believe I am running in verbose mode (see last line in xml file) but the console output is still nothing.

Comment: @lololololol Please use `@username` in your comment to address a specific user you're replying to.

Comment: This is very strange. You should have a lot of output with `ant -verbose`. What does `ant -diagnostics` output if you run it somewhere else (where there's no `build.xml`)?

Comment: @lexicore Yes, it is very strange.  I attached the build log of the verbose output, btw.  Not sure if any clues are in there.

Comment: The build log says the build sequence is `compile, run` as I expect, but again no console output for the `run` target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jar step is not inside a "target".  Create a target named "jar" that depends on "compile", that creates a jar (your "jar" block should work here), and have target "run" depend on it.

It looks like you will need to add the jar you create to your "run" "java" classpath as well.

Comment: But the run target is not even running.

Comment: What command are you using to invoke Ant, and what is the output you are seeing?

Comment: I right-click on the `build.xml` file and click Run As -> Ant Build.

Comment: Your IDE is running the 'compile' target.  I don't know your IDE, so I don't know what to tell you to do differently.

Comment: The key is the line "Build sequence for target compile is..." - that is the target it is processing.  The fact that it also tells you the complete build sequence may be misleading you.

Comment: You can run from the command line - set ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME, and add %ANT_HOME%\bin to the path.  Then you can run "ant compile" and "ant run" (and "ant jar" if you add it.)

Comment: With "ant -v" you will see that it is telling you the target that it was asked to invoke above the complete build sequence.

Comment: The IDE is `Eclipse`. The output is in the OP.  Got it to run, but now I am getting run errors.